How to integrate Automatic password autofill in iOS App (UIKit)for already existing users
We are newly integrating Password Autofill in our iOS app.
Steps I have done

I have a created one apple-app-site-association file and hosted at https://{domain}/apple-app-site-association.
Added Associated domain entitlement in my Xcode project
I have set the textContentType property on any relevant input views for my text input view to display the right AutoFill suggestions

Here my question is for newly created users , passwords are saved in iCloud during registration process(Signup) and it retrieves it from there later during login.
Is there a way i can save existing users credentials when they login without signup, as it was already done long back?

Only if you force them to reauthenticate, thereby getting them to enter their username and password and providing an opportunity to save them
